# Good WPF focused blogs and/or podcasts?

Tags: c#, wpf, blogs, podcast

Are there any good [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) focused blogs and/or podcasts out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jaime Rodriguez, a WPF Technical Evangelist at Microsoft (you'll see him on a handful of Channel 9 videos), maintains a pretty [exhaustive list of WPF bloggers](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/pages/wpf-bloggers.aspx), broken down into Microsoft and non-Microsoft.  Right now, it's 79 blogs long, and includes every major high-quality WPF blog I can think of.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some:

> - [Lester's WPF blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/default.aspx)
> - [Josh Smith on WPF](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 4):

My favorite WPF blog has to be [Bea Stollnitz's](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/). I've found it very useful on numerous occasions.

Comment: +1 from me. Too bad she doesn't update it anymore...

Answer (score 3):

[Sacha Barber](http://sachabarber.net/) has some great WPF stuff. He's very well respected in the [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) community (has won many awards and is a multiple C# MVP). You can find many of his WPF articles [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=569009).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some videos:
http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx

Also:

[The Official Microsoft WPF and Windows Forms Site](http://windowsclient.net/)

[.NET Framework Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[.NET Rocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/) has some excellent WPF podcasts, just look through their previous shows.

Answer (score 1):

I like to visit [WPF WTFs](http://jerryclin.wordpress.com/) after a long day of trying to get WPF to do what I want.